# Undelete the List of free antivirus solutions for Windows

Tags: support, status-declined, exact-duplicates, deleted-questions

I went out to search for antivirus solutions, and quite a few questions are on super user for this. I believe a question like "what free antivirus solutions are there" is a valid question for this (but not "what is the best antivirus")

So I found a huge long string of questions that were all mostly the same, and all closed with very few answers as a duplicate of [this question](https://superuser.com/questions/2/free-antivirus-solutions-for-windows). That question though is now deleted, and along with it, quite a bit of information.

Could this question please be undeleted, or all the duplicate questions pointed to a question with more than 1 answer

Comment: Will be consolidated as part of [Alternatives and the campfire lists are better in the tag wiki, within reason](http://meta.superuser.com/q/4372)

Comment: @Sathya I made my defense on that question now. http://meta.superuser.com/a/4382/14013

Comment: Top answers in that topic: Microsoft Security Essentials, Avast, Avira, AVG, in that order. These four combined have a 290 score. Totally unexpected.

Comment: Answers to that topic are very unspecific, require no particular knowledge to come up with, have very little value (since you get way more general data from Wikipedia), are quickly outdated (especially regarding the merits of each virus scanner), and the bits of actually valuable information are drowned in a sea of generic data available elsewhere. In addition, no specific topic (e.g. "I have the following N machines with configuration X and some network hardware, how do I virus protect the NAS devices?") will be answered by them.

Answer (score 5):

For the record, here is the list of those mentioned sorted by the order of votes. Also included, the number of questions tagged about the AV program.

It reads like this:

> antivirus program - questions asked with this tag/upvotes on question

- [ms-security-essentials](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/ms-security-essentials) - 84/140
- [avast](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/avast) - 25/57
- [avira](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/avira) - 2/46
- [avg-antivirus](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/avg-antivirus) - 39/44
- [clamav](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/clamav) - 1/23
- None - 23
- [comodo-firewall](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/comodo-firewall) - 3/10 (the closest for Comodo)
- Malwarebytes - 0/6
- Panda Cloud - 0/5
- VirusTotal.com - 0/5
- Dr. Web CureIt! - 0/4
- HouseCall - 0/3
- [kaspersky](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/kaspersky) - 27/3
- ThreatFire - 0/2
- Prevx - 0/1

The list of tags here would better as a section in the tag wiki for [antivirus](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/antivirus) showing which questions are actively being used and asked about on the site. No tag means no questions or users. Why even bring them up?

"What free/paid/alternative programs are there of X?" is never a valid question. It's a product recommendation of many things thrown into the sandpits of upvotes and downvotes of The Coliseum of Popularity and not about any single constructive thing.

It's a question before you have a question.

Answer (score 2):

As mentioned, we'd be [moving alternatives](https://meta.superuser.com/q/4372)-to-x, best-x, probably hidden-features-of-x to [tag wikis](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/tags/tag-wiki/info).